# How to return the loc/index (row and column) of a searched item in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, search, indexing

I am searching for a sub-string in a Pandas dateframe.

```
tmp = Metadata_sheet_0.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('sRNA spacer'), axis=1)
```

It returns a dataframe of the same size, with every element True or False. I would like the indexes of all Trues, not another dataframe of Trues/Falses.

How to do this Pandas' way without resorting to for loops?

Thank you!

Comment: Use: `Metadata_sheet_0[Metadata_sheet_0.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('sRNA spacer'), axis=1)]`.

Comment: can you provide a real minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming such example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,1,2],[1,5,1]], columns=list('ABC'))

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  2
2  1  5  1
```

you can use a boolean mask and `stack`:

```
df.where(df.eq(1)).stack()
```

output:

```
0  A    1.0
1  B    1.0
2  A    1.0
   C    1.0
dtype: float64
```

to only get the coordinates:

```
df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().index.to_list()
```

output:

```
[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'C')]
```

Comment: Thanks! df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().index.to_list() was all I needed.